Override parent class attribute in child class (as a function of parent class attribute)
Let's say, I have a parent class Parent defined already, with an attribute called attribute defined as 5. I am building a child class Child, however, need to set the attribute value as half of the parent attribute value. How to do this in python?
class Parent:
    attribute = 5

class Child(Parent):
    attribute = self.attribute / 2
    # obviously fails, since 'self' is not defined


What's the use case for this?

You can refer to the attribute by using the parent class name:
class Child(Parent):
    attribute = Parent.attribute/2


You can use a class decorator to modify the attribute.
import copy

def half_attribute(cls):
    cls = copy.copy(cls)  # Makes the function pure
    cls.attribute = cls.attribute / 2
    return cls

@half_attribute
class Child(Parent):
    pass

This avoids explicitly referring to the parent class as in John Gordon's answer.

I don't think there's any great benefit to making half_attribute pure. As applied, cls is a reference to Child, but cls.attribute on the right-hand side of the assignment would still resolve to Parent.attribute before creating Child.attribute.

@chepner I added that because decorators can also be used as plain functions, like hypothetically, NewChild = half_attribute(OldChild), and in that case, we don't want to modify OldChild.

Can be, but I think it's worth deciding whether it's meant to be, because you're making an unnecessary copy in the decorator case.
